# Let's get critical: Feb 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Sports Stack Exchange](http://sports.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://sports.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Comment: No longer relevant as the site is out of beta.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Final Results

- [What is the closest any team has come to playing a home Super Bowl?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7389/what-is-the-closest-any-team-has-come-to-playing-a-home-super-bowl)

**Net Score: 9** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Is 100 the maximum possible batting average?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7357/is-100-the-maximum-possible-batting-average)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 9, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [What is the legal basis for fining players for out-of-game actions?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7336/what-is-the-legal-basis-for-fining-players-for-out-of-game-actions)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [game matching Phil Rizzuto call in Meat Loaf song?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7286/game-matching-phil-rizzuto-call-in-meat-loaf-song)

**Net Score: 6** (Excellent: 6, Satisfactory: 10, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Seattle Seahawks' Legion of Boom](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7407/seattle-seahawks-legion-of-boom)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 7, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How does a paintball marker / ball / shot curve? e.g. what is its line of flight?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7320/how-does-a-paintball-marker-ball-shot-curve-e-g-what-is-its-line-of-flight)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 8, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Lateral Passes in the NFL](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7437/lateral-passes-in-the-nfl)

**Net Score: 1** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [calculate winning percentage with a tie](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7396/calculate-winning-percentage-with-a-tie)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 4, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [Why does anyone choose to bat first?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7276/why-does-anyone-choose-to-bat-first)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 2, Satisfactory: 9, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [why do a bowler use a white marker disc?](https://sports.stackexchange.com/questions/7474/why-do-a-bowler-use-a-white-marker-disc)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 7)

---